# Power option's PDE

Tags: black-scholes-pde, pde

I am looking to understand the PDE of Power Options in *Paull Willmot on Quantitative Finance (2nd Ed)*, Ch. 8.9 - Formulae for Power Options (p. 149).

Suppose the payoff depends on the asset price at expiry raised to some power i.e.: $\text{Payoff}(S^\alpha)$. If we write
$ Z = S^\alpha $  the standard Black-Scholes PDE:

$${\frac {\partial V}{\partial t}}
+{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}S^{2}{\frac {\partial ^{2}V}{\partial S^{2}}}
+rS{\frac {\partial V}{\partial S}}-rV=0$$

The books says it can be transformed to the following:

$${\frac {\partial V}{\partial t}}
+{\frac {1}{2}}\alpha^2\sigma ^{2}Z^2{\frac {\partial ^{2}V}{\partial Z^{2}}}
+\alpha\left(\frac {1}{2}\sigma ^{2}(\alpha -1 ) + r\right)Z{\frac {\partial V}{\partial S}}-rV=0$$

**Where does the $\alpha\left(\frac {1}{2}\sigma ^{2}(\alpha -1 ) + r\right)$ term come from? Actually, only the $\alpha\left(\frac {1}{2}\sigma ^{2}(\alpha -1 ) \right)$ bit I cannot figure out. $\alpha r $'s source is clear.**

I get an entirely different expression for the delta term, $rS{\frac {\partial V}{\partial S}}$, when I change the variables. Namely:

$${\frac {\partial V}{\partial S}} = {\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial S}} =  {\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}} \alpha S ^{\alpha-1} $$ and so:

$$rS{\frac {\partial V}{\partial S}}
= rS {\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}} \alpha S ^{\alpha-1}
= r \alpha S^\alpha {\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}}
= r \alpha Z{\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}}$$

Comment: You need to do the same for the diffusion term d2V/dS2

Comment: Thanks, that is correct! I must've made an error when I expanded that term initially hence the missing component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by James, the expansion of the ${\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}S^{2}{\frac {\partial ^{2}V}{\partial S^{2}}}$ term yields:

$$
\frac {\partial ^{2}V}{\partial S^{2}}
= \frac {\partial}{\partial S}\left(\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}\alpha S ^{\alpha-1}\right)
= \frac {\partial}{\partial S}\left(\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}\right)\alpha S ^{\alpha-1}
+ \frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}\alpha (\alpha-1)S ^{\alpha-2}
\\= \alpha S ^{\alpha-1}\frac {\partial^2 V}{\partial Z^2}\frac {\partial Z}{\partial S}
+ \frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}\alpha (\alpha-1)S ^{\alpha-2}
\\ = \frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}\alpha (\alpha-1)S ^{\alpha-2} + \alpha^2 (S ^{\alpha-1})^2\frac {\partial^2 V}{\partial Z^2} 
$$
And so:
$${\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}S^{2}{\frac {\partial ^{2}V}{\partial S^{2}}} 
= \frac {1}{2}\sigma ^{2} \left(\alpha (\alpha-1)S ^{\alpha} \frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}
+ \alpha^2 (S ^{\alpha})^2\frac {\partial^2 V}{\partial Z^2} \right)
= \frac {1}{2}\sigma ^{2} \left(\alpha (\alpha-1)Z\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}
+ \alpha^2 Z^2\frac {\partial^2 V}{\partial Z^2} \right)$$
which explains the additional term of $\frac {\partial V}{\partial Z}$ from the question.